# Kaminari pagination breaking with where clause on has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

We have two models

**Book** `has_many :reviews`

**Review** `belongs_to :book`

A **Review** has a rating (from 1 to 5).

```
book1
  review1 - rating 5
  review2 - rating 5
  review3 - rating 4
book2 
  review4 - rating 5
book3
  review5 - rating 5
```

Let say I need to filter all books that have a rating of 5 I would do something like:

```
@books = Book.includes(:reviews)
             .where(reviews: { rating: 5 })
             .page(params[:page]).per(3)
```

The issue is that I get the following

```
book1
  review1 - rating 5
  review2 - rating 5
book2 
  review4 - rating 5
```

This is not working and is breaking pagination as the `@books.total_count` is 2 not 3 (which is the triggering pagination as we require per(3)). How would you fix it ?

I would expect the query to render 3 Books with all the reviews matching the where clause

```
book1
  review1 - rating 5
  review2 - rating 5
book2 
  review4 - rating 5
book3
  review5 - rating 5
```

Comment: `books.total_count` will return the uniq size of objects retrieved by your query, so if `@books.total_count` is 2 and you have 2 books in response, it works fine. Are you sure that there are more than 2 different books matching your query?

Comment: Okay, the issue is not the total_count but the fact that kaminari is allowing the pagination only if the count of objects is equal to the .per(X) value. This results in the next_page link not to being displayed.

Comment: @Joe actually the issue lies in the query itself as the per(3) seems to be applied on the association, not on the Books. This is why we have 2 books with 3 reviews (therefore breaking the pagination as we need 3 books). How should I do to have the limit set on Book not on Review ?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination can be fixed by using

```
@books = Book.includes(:reviews)
             .where(reviews: { rating: 5 })

@books = Kaminari.paginate_array(@books).page(params[:page]).per(4)
```

This works as expected but is not performant as there is no limit applied to @books on the first query. I think this should be optimized by using manual pagination.